# CSS optimisation, nested selectors, and browser indexing of ID's/class names

Tags: css, optimization, browser

When rendering web pages and applying styles, do browsers index ID's and class names for efficient search, or does it traverse the entire DOM from the top each time an ID or class name is specified to reach the correct element.

I'm wondering for optimisation reasons, and whether it's worth giving the browser hints (longer selectors) to where an object of a certain ID is. I.e.

```
#container #one-of-many-container-siblings #my-id
```

instead of:

```
#my-id
```

Will the former yield better performance if the DOM is quite large?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It actually works the opposite way to what you're thinking.

Remember that browsers parse CSS selectors right to left.

This:

```
#container #one-of-many-container-siblings #my-id
```

will take more steps to match than this:

```
#my-id
```

See: http://www.css-101.org/descendant-selector/go_fetch_yourself.php

Considering the question you've just asked, I recommend you read this article:

http://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/

It will help you write more efficient selectors:

```
#main-navigation {   }      /* ID (Fastest) */
body.home #page-wrap {   }  /* ID */
.main-navigation {   }      /* Class */
ul li a.current {   }       /* Class *
ul {   }                    /* Tag */
ul li a {  }                /* Tag */
* {   }                     /* Universal (Slowest) */
#content [title='home']     /* Universal */
```

Comment: I see, very interesting. I was under the impression that the browser parses the stylesheet and then applies each style, i.e. encounter a selector, find element(s) it matches, apply the style properties, go to next selector. However it would seem as though it actually goes through the HTML document, and for each element it goes through all the CSS rules and find which one(s) apply. Hence a right to left read performs better for exclusion rather than inclusion.

Comment: Thanks ever so much for the information — really useful! I had a quick search before I posed the question and I struggled to find any detail as to how (behind the scenes) browsers process and render these documents. Good to know a bit more about how these things work!

Answer (score 2):

The definition of an ID in HTML/CSS is a single instance of an element. Assuming you're following that rule, then all you need is the ID of that element. The browser will search through and find that element and stop.

With your "hinting" one, it will first search for the first item, then the second, then the third, before stopping. This, as you can probably see, is more inefficient.

When dealing with classes, this can get a little more ambiguous and fuzzy, but the general rule is the fewer the selectors, the better. If you find yourself doing three or four or five selectors, it might be worth considering a little refactoring, such as adding classes or IDs in strategic places, or even not being so specific with your CSS selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Using the shorter version will always be faster because there a fewer checks being performed, however I don't know why on would need to optimize the CSS on a page.

Comment: Efficiency can be a factor in large web sites/apps. Take a look at the link that `thirtydot` provided in his answer: http://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/

Answer (score 1):

its best to use 2 or less selectors as a rule of thumb for performance.